# Domain restriction does not do anything

Tags: python, django

Hello I have a simple form where I want to save information. I added the domain restriction in my forms but it still saves emails with other email domains. I am new to django, so maybe it is an easy task, thanks.

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models


    class WPGroup(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=False)
        number=models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)
        bolum=models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=False)
        mail=models.EmailField(max_length=128,blank=False)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

`forms.py`

```
    from django import forms
    from .models import WPGroup
    
    
    class WPGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model=WPGroup
            fields=['name','number','bolum','mail']
    
    
        def clean_email(self):
            email = self.cleaned_data['mail']
            if "@itu.edu.tr" not in email:
                raise forms.ValidationError("You must include @itu.edu.tr")
            return email
```

`views.py`

```
    class WPGroupView(generic.CreateView):
        template_name='wp.html'
        form=WPGroupForm
        model=WPGroup
        fields=['name','mail','bolum','number']
        success_url='success/'
```

Comment: Your field seems to be called "mail", so the method should be `clean_mail`, not `clean_email`.

Comment: I changed it but it is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `form_class` attribut instead of `form` :

```py
    class WPGroupView(generic.CreateView):
        template_name='wp.html'
        form_class=WPGroupForm
        model=WPGroup
        success_url='success/'
```

Also, your validate method must be name `clean_**fieldname**` so it should be `clean_mail` instead of `clean_email`.

Comment: thank you it worked but both form_class and fields are not permitted to use together, I changed it and maybe you can delete it also in your answer.